# JavaScript & jQuery not working after fiddle update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, kineticjs, jsfiddle

I found this jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/wQ8YA/19/ on the internet.I'm trying to modify the code according to suit my needs.The problem is that the moment I make some changes like

```
//create a group
var group = new Kinetic.Group({
draggable: true //make group draggable
});
var rec = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 10,
    y: 330,
    width: 600,
    height: 600

  });
 group.add(rec);

// use of
var myRoom = createGroup(100, 200);
myRoom.add(new Kinetic.Circle({config}));
```

In the code and click the UPDATE button all the jQuery UI effects disappear. I don't know why this is happening.Is it because of my code or something else??

The fidddle containing the above changes is http://jsfiddle.net/wQ8YA/25/

Comment: Did you check the Javascript console? It's complaining of a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below statement is incorrect

```
myRoom.add(new Kinetic.Circle({config}));
```

instead it should be

```
myRoom.add(new Kinetic.Circle(config));
```

I assume `config` itself is JSON object so you need not to enclose it in braces ( `{ }` )

Comment: +1: Yep, works fine after that change: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wQ8YA/26/

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a declaration of the `config` variable anywhere in the code. That gets rid of the error, but it's probably not doing anything useful.

Comment: OP might have added them in his fiddle and/or he might have playfully deleted it from fiddle as now I also can not see it.